# What does "cannot Convert vector<int>* to int" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, error-handling, mergesort

I have the error:

Error   1   error C2664: 'int practiceMergeSort(int,int,std::vector>)' :
    cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector> *' to 'int'

I have no idea what may be the cause of the error or what the error is even telling me.

EDIT:

```
Function Prototypes
int practiceMergeSort(int, int, vector<int>);
int practiceMerge(vector<int>, int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int numOfItems;
    srand(int(time(0))); // Initialize the random number generator
    printf("Algorithm Comparison\n\n");

    printf("Selection Sort\n");
    //selectionSort();
    practiceSelectionSort(); // Fully functioning version

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "\nMerge Sort\n";

    cout << "Enter the number of items to be sorted: ";
    cin >> numOfItems;

    vector<int> mergeArray(numOfItems);

    cout << "Value of numOfItems: " << numOfItems << "\n";

    cout << "Array values: \n";
    for (int x = 0; x < numOfItems; x++)
    {
        mergeArray[x] = rand();
        cout << mergeArray[x] << "\n";
    }

    practiceMergeSort(&mergeArray, 0, numOfItems);
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Testing of the Array Filler
    //printf("\nArray Filler\n");
    //arrayFiller();

    cout << "\n\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

int practiceMergeSort(vector<int> mergeArray[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        practiceMergeSort(mergeArray, low, mid);
        practiceMergeSort(mergeArray, mid + 1, high);
        practiceMerge(mergeArray, low, mid, high);
    }
    return 0;
}

int practiceMerge(vector<int> mergeArray[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    vector<int> b[10000];
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (mergeArray[i] <= mergeArray[j])
            b[k++] = mergeArray[i++];
        else
            b[k++] = mergeArray[j++];
        }
    while (i <= mid)
        b[k++] = mergeArray[i++];

    while (j <= high)
        b[k++] = mergeArray[j++];

    k--;
    while (k >= 0) {
        mergeArray[low + k] = b[k];
        k--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And we have no idea what it could mean, since you didn't post the code that causes the error.

Comment: Post the relevant piece of code, else there is no way to help you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also, that error message is really clear. Are you trying to learn C++ by trial and error? If so, stop that and learn it from a good book or tutorial instead.

Comment: Apolgies, I am implementing the Merge Sort algorithm so that I can test its efficiency at different amounts of inputs. Although I am experienced with C and some C++, I am not as experienced with vectors, which is where my problem lies. Again I apologize for not explaining this outright.

Comment: How can you claim experience with C and yet be confused when the compiler is telling you that you are passing arguments to a function in the wrong order?

Comment: You have too many `[]` in your code. And why are you mixing C-style and C++-style I/O like that? You really should systematically read a your book.

Comment: The error is telling you that you tried to pass a `std::vector<int>*` into a parameter that takes `int`. It even tells you which parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the very function prototypes don't match the actual function definitions:

```
//Function Prototypes
int practiceMergeSort(int, int, vector<int>);
int practiceMerge(vector<int>, int, int, int);

// Functions
int practiceMergeSort(vector<int> mergeArray[], int low, int high)
{
//...
}

int practiceMerge(vector<int> mergeArray[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
//...
}
```

Change the prototypes to:

```
int practiceMergeSort(vector<int> mergeArray[], int low, int high);
int practiceMerge(vector<int> mergeArray[], int low, int mid, int high);
```

Or if you want to keep using prototypes with unnamed arguments:

```
int practiceMergeSort(vector<int> [], int, int);
int practiceMerge(vector<int> [], int, int, int);
```

That will make it compile.